# How to pass a variable into the HTML of a WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to pass in a variable from state into the HTML of a React Native WebView but am having some trouble.

I was able to get this working when using a URI instead of HTML in the WebView:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      foo: props.navigation.getParam('foo', 'NO-FOO')
    }
  }
  render() {
    const url = 'http://example.com/Results.aspx?entry=1&foo=' + this.state.foo + '&css=default'
    return (
      <WebView source={{ uri: url }} />
    );
  }
```

When I try to do the same with HTML, it works if BAR is hard-coded:

```
  render() {
    const html = '<html><head></head><body><script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/LaunchWidget.js?widget=Posting&css=default&foo=BAR&showheader=1></script></body></html>'
    return (
      <WebView source={{ html: html }} />
    );
```

But when I try to do something similar with HTML, the WebView just renders a blank page:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      foo: props.navigation.getParam('foo', 'NO-FOO')
    }
    console.log('foo: ', this.state.foo); // this works as expected but the URL below does not work unless BAR is hard-coded
  }
  render() {
    const html = '<html><head></head><body><script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/LaunchWidget.js?widget=Posting&css=default&foo=' + this.state.foo + '&showheader=1></script></body></html>'
    return (
      <WebView source={{ html: html }} />
    );
```

Note: BAR in this case is a 7-digit number

Comment: Close the script tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/LaunchWidget.js?widget=Posting&css=default&foo=' + this.state.foo + '&showheader=1"></script>`

Comment: Check out this answer I made https://stackoverflow.com/a/57065662/7602110

Comment: Thanks, @CarlosAbraham. I'll research injecting JS to see if that gets me closer, but I'm not sure your answer works the same when the variable is in the src URL rather than the HTML -- let me know if I'm mistaken!

Comment: Actually @MaximeLaunois your comment helped! I was missing the closing quote mark at the send of src=

I love SO!